# Automatic resizing of QWidgets

Tags: python, pyqt5

For some time now I have been trying to adapt a QFrame according to the width of the application window it is programmed in Python. I have searched for many tutorials on the subject but no one has been able to give me a solution.

Basically, I have a Qframe that only has to adapt in length for the entire app screen while maintaining a distance of a few pixels from the edge of the window.

I have already tried several solutions, none of which brought me to a conclusion:

- set a general layout and one for the individual QFrame

- remove the .setGeometry() and use the .move()

- use .setContentsMargins() for the layout

This is only the first part of the code:

```
class app(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        #GUI PRINCIPALE
        MainWindow.setObjectName("app")
        MainWindow.resize(1060, 580)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);\n""border-radius:4px;\n""")
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(vb.app_logo))
        MainWindow.setMinimumWidth(820)
        MainWindow.setMinimumHeight(530)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        #layout principali
        #ToolBar
        self.Ftoolbar = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Ftoolbar.move(10, 10)
        self.Ftoolbar.setGeometry(vb.barra_degli_strumenti_dimensioni)
        self.Ftoolbar.setFixedHeight(31)
        self.Ftoolbar.setStyleSheet(vb.proprieta_frame)
        self.Ftoolbar.setLineWidth(2)
        self.Ftoolbar.setMidLineWidth(5)
        self.Ftoolbar.setObjectName("Ftoolbar")
        self.Ftoolbar.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.Ftoolbar_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.Ftoolbar.setLayout(self.Ftoolbar_layout)

        main_layout.addWidget(self.Ftoolbar)
```

and this is what I get

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCWMS.png)

the QFrame in question can be seen in the empty space: it places itself in the centre of the window

Comment: You need to set a vertical layout for the central widget, add a spacer on top, the frame, and the rest of the UI, which probably will be in a *nested* layout within the main one. You could easily do it from Designer, but it can be done by code too. What you should certainly **not** do is editing pyuic generated files, it's considered bad practice and it's discouraged (as the warning on the top of those files also suggests). Please follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).